# Meaning of probability of the intersection of two events

Tags: probability

Suppose X is a random variable of a rolling 6-side die. Suppose A is the event that the outcome is even.

The example asks for the conditional probability of X=k, given A.

The answer to this is 1/3. We also know that P(A) = 1/2.

If we write down the formula of the conditional probability and solve for the probability of the intersection of the two events, the outcomes is 1/6.

I cant understand why the probability of the intersection is 1/6. What actually means for the two events to happen at the same time. How could we find this probability without using the conditional probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of the intersection $\{X=k\}\cap A$ depends of the value of $k$:

- if $k$ is odd then cannot be odd and even at the same time so the probability would be zero, in other words $P(\{X=k\}\cap A)=P(\emptyset )=0$.
- if $k$ is even then $\{X=k\}\subset A$ so $\{X=k\}\cap A=\{X=k\}$, therefore $P(\{X=k\}\cap A)=P(\{X=k\})=\frac1{6}$.

Comment: I just want to ask, if k is even, wouldn't also be than A is subset of {X=k} so that the intersection is A? Therefore the probability would be 1/2? Thanks.

Comment: @Toni Ivanov :   If k is Even is $\{X=k\} \subset A$ so the probability of intersection is $\frac{1}{6}$ as perfectly explained before

Comment: @Toni we have that $A=X^{-1}(\{2,4,6\})$ and $\{X=k\}:=X^{-1}(\{k\})$. Then when $k\in\{2,4,6\}$ we have that $\{X=k\}\subset A$